# C++ mathematical vector class

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, mathematics, overloading

I plan to implement a simple simulation in C++, which requires mathematical vectors. The following header file contains the complete vector class with all it's method definitions. By overloading several operators, I tried to make the class more usable. For example: the components of the vector can be modified using `v[0] = 5;` instead of using `v.set(0, 5);`.

Nervetheless, the header file seems quite long and the class could probably be rewritten in a modern way. Additionally, some vector operations could parallelized. Any tips for improving the code quality and performance?

Header file:

```
#ifndef __COLUMNVECTOR_H__
#define __COLUMNVECTOR_H__

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
class ColumnVector
{
  public:
    const unsigned int DIMENSION;

  private:
    std::vector<T> entries;

  public:
    ColumnVector(unsigned int);
    ColumnVector(const std::vector<T> &);
    T &operator[](unsigned int);
    bool operator==(const ColumnVector<T> &) const;
    bool operator!=(const ColumnVector<T> &) const;
    ColumnVector<T> operator+(const ColumnVector<T> &) const;
    ColumnVector<T> operator-(const ColumnVector<T> &) const;
    ColumnVector<T> &operator+=(const ColumnVector<T> &);
    ColumnVector<T> &operator-=(const ColumnVector<T> &);
    T operator*(const ColumnVector<T> &)const;

  private:
    bool equals(const ColumnVector<T> &) const;
};

template <typename T>
ColumnVector<T>::ColumnVector(unsigned int d) : DIMENSION(d),
                                                entries(d)
{
}

template <typename T>
ColumnVector<T>::ColumnVector(const std::vector<T> &v) : DIMENSION(v.size()),
                                                         entries(v)
{
}

template <typename T>
T &ColumnVector<T>::operator[](unsigned int i)
{
    if (i >= DIMENSION)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Not enough dimensions!");
    }
    return entries[i];
}

template <typename T>
bool ColumnVector<T>::equals(const ColumnVector<T> &o) const
{
    return (DIMENSION == o.DIMENSION) &&
           (entries == o.entries);
}

template <typename T>
bool ColumnVector<T>::operator==(const ColumnVector<T> &o) const
{
    return *this.equals(o);
}

template <typename T>
bool ColumnVector<T>::operator!=(const ColumnVector<T> &o) const
{
    return !*this.equals(o);
}

template <typename T>
ColumnVector<T> ColumnVector<T>::operator+(const ColumnVector<T> &o) const
{
    if (DIMENSION != o.DIMENSION)
    {
        throw std::length_error("Dimensions must be equal!");
    }
    ColumnVector<T> result(DIMENSION);
    std::transform(entries.begin(), entries.end(),
                   o.entries.begin(), result.entries.begin(),
                   std::plus<T>());
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
ColumnVector<T> ColumnVector<T>::operator-(const ColumnVector<T> &o) const
{
    if (DIMENSION != o.DIMENSION)
    {
        throw std::length_error("Dimensions must be equal!");
    }
    ColumnVector<T> result(DIMENSION);
    std::transform(entries.begin(), entries.end(),
                   o.entries.begin(), result.entries.begin(),
                   std::minus<T>());
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
ColumnVector<T> &ColumnVector<T>::operator+=(const ColumnVector<T> &o)
{
    if (DIMENSION != o.DIMENSION)
    {
        throw std::length_error("Dimensions must be equal!");
    }
    std::transform(entries.begin(), entries.end(),
                   o.entries.begin(), entries.begin(),
                   std::plus<T>());
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
ColumnVector<T> &ColumnVector<T>::operator-=(const ColumnVector<T> &o)
{
    if (DIMENSION != o.DIMENSION)
    {
        throw std::length_error("Dimensions must be equal!");
    }
    std::transform(entries.begin(), entries.end(),
                   o.entries.begin(), entries.begin(),
                   std::minus<T>());
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
T ColumnVector<T>::operator*(const ColumnVector<T> &o) const
{
    if (DIMENSION != o.DIMENSION)
    {
        throw std::length_error("Dimensions must be equal!");
    }
    std::vector<T> multiplied(DIMENSION);
    std::transform(entries.begin(), entries.end(),
                   o.entries.begin(), multiplied.begin(),
                   std::multiplies<T>());
    return std::accumulate(multiplied.begin(), multiplied.end(), 0);
}

#endif
```

Usage example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ColumnVector.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ColumnVector<int> cv(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3});
    ColumnVector<int> cv2(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3});
    cout << cv * cv2 << "\n" << cv + cv2 << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'd like to recommend making the dimension non-`const`. Changing the dimension is a legal operation, for example when projecting spatial coordinates to the *(x, y)* plane, or when doing affine transforms and working with homogenous coordinates.

Then... that's the usual approach - "*has-a*" `std::vector<T>`. That's reasonable most times, but maybe not *this time*. Because this way, you will end up rebuilding much of the vector interface... soon you will notice an `operator[]()` is not enough: you will need a `operator[]() const`, too, as soon you have `const ColumnVector`!

As

1. the operations on `std::vector` and `ColumnVector` are easily distinguishable by topic, and
2. it's virtually impossible to *corrupt* a `ColumnVector` if operations like `push_back` are available (that would just change the dimension - it will *still* be a valid `ColumnVector` after that),

I'd recommend to brace yourself and... use "*is-a*". In other words, to **subclass** `std::vector`... This will greatly simplify the interface you will have to write, and you can focus on the *mathematical* characteristics of `ColumnVector`. Because in this case, there is no need to hide/shadow/wrap-away all these nice `std::vector` constructors and members.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are missing some important constructors, namely move and default constructors. Also some of the operators like `operator+` could use move semantics.
2. Also I would expect an `operator *=` for multiplying by a scalar
3. `unsigned int` should be `size_t` or just plain `unsigned`
4. Your multiplication operator is unnecessarily complicated and wasteful. A simple loop over the elements of both vectors should be sufficient.

Comment: You cannot semantically correctly move from this `ColumnVector` as `DIMENSION` is `const`. Remember that a moved-from object should be in a valid but arbitrary state.

Comment: Thats true, however the purpose of dimension is not really clear to me, other than that it is not a std::vector but rather close to a std::array

Comment: As for 4, `std::inner_product` seems to fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

1. Is there a reason you are duplicating the `std::vector`'s `.size()`?
   Maybe you should use a `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` instead of the vector...
2. It's pretty unusual for fields to have all-uppercase names. That's normally reserved for non-instance constants.
3. Reduce coupling. That means make it a non-friend non-member if you can.